# Scaling datasets for multi-dataset time series

Tags: time-series, dataset, normalization, validation

Suppose that I have training data with dimension $(N,H,F)$, where $N$ represents the number of different datasets, $H$ is the history size and $F$ is the input size. Normalizing each dataset over the history dimension, and using (for example) a standard-scaler, I should be getting a mean and std tensors $\mu,\sigma$, both with shape $(N,F)$. Namely, for each dataset $n$, we normalize each feature $f$ across the entire history $H$.

Now, given a validation set with dimensions $(V,H,F)$, it seems that $\mu$ and $\sigma$ cannot be used for normalization as $N\ne V$ (at least not necessarily)

One naive solution is to discard the dataset association and normalize the training data when it is reshaped as $(N\times H, F)$, generating $\mu,\sigma$ with shape $(1,F)$. This seems problematic as the different datasets do not necessarily represent samples from the same underlying distribution.

Any suggestions?